# Iphone 4 won't display game background

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite, sprite-kit

We are testing a game on multiple devices and have found that our large background sprites (using sprite kit and at 3408x640 pixels) are displaying and moving just fine on iphone 5s, 5, and 4s, but when it comes to iphone 4, they simply don't show up and no errors get thrown.

Is this a limitation of memory or the device's image rules or something?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPhone 4 maximum texture size is 2048x2048. Same for iPad 1. Use smaller textures, at least on the affected devices.

http://www.uchidacoonga.com/2012/04/quick-tip-max-texture-size/

Answer (score -2):

Very strange problem, its not suppose to not show it at all... but if that's the case way not just ask if not Iphone 5:

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)
```

Then scale:

```
[ImageManipulation scale:imageAfterCrop toSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, 640.0)];

+ (UIImage*)scale: (UIImage*)image toSize: (CGSize)size {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return scaledImage;
}
```

?